# Multiline RPROMPT in zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt

I know you can define multiline prompts in zsh:

```
PROMPT='
test
→ '
```

But I was wondering, why can't you define multiline right prompts? I tried:

```
RPROMPT='
test
still test '
```

but nothing shows up. Is this possible?

Comment: A multiline right prompt will simply fail silently. Not clear why is that, but it's totally possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the desired (if I guess right) effect by using the `precmd` function, which is executed every time before the prompt is displayed, to print additional lines above the prompt.

Use for example this code

```
precmd() {
  LEFT="The time is"
  RIGHT="$(date) "
  RIGHTWIDTH=$(($COLUMNS-${#LEFT}))
  print $LEFT${(l:$RIGHTWIDTH::.:)RIGHT}
}
PS1="foo > "
RPS1="bar"
```

**Explanation**

- `$LEFT` and `$RIGHT` hold the strings for the left and right side, resp. You can use the output of command with the `$(...)` syntax.
- `$RIGHTWIDTH` is the difference of the current terminal width (stored by *zsh* in the `$COLUMNS` parameter) and the width of the left string. `$((...))` is for mathematical expressions
- The magic comes with `${(l:$RIGHTWIDTH::.:)RIGHT}`, where the parameter `$RIGHT` is left-padded (`l`) by dots (omit the last `:.:` if you want spaces) to the length of `$RIGHTWIDTH`.
- Print the additional line. Repeat the commands if you want more lines.
- `PS1` and `RPS1` are shorter for `PROMPT` and `RPROMPT`.

**Demo**

```
The time is............................................Fri, Sep 18, 2015  8:20:22 PM 
foo > _                                                                          bar
```

Comment: Great solution, but one has to be careful if `LEFT` or `RIGHT` contains ANSI escape sequences (e.g. colors). To compute string length ignoring ansi escapes, we can do it as `$(( ${#${(S%%)str//(\%([KF1]|)\{*\}|\%[Bbkf])}} ))`

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently not impossible to set a multi-line right prompt: [this one](https://gist.github.com/romkatv/2a107ef9314f0d5f76563725b42f7cab) manages that. However, I would say it does so like this:

```shell
 local top_left='%F{blue}%~%f'
  local top_right="%F{green}${git_branch}%f"
  local bottom_left='%B%F{%(?.green.red)}%#%f%b '
  local bottom_right='%F{yellow}%T%f'

  local REPLY
  fill-line "$top_left" "$top_right"
  PROMPT=$REPLY$'\n'$bottom_left
  RPROMPT=$bottom_right
```

By having a `PROMPT` occupy top left and right, as well as bottom left, and the RPROMPT occupy bottom right. Still, RPROMPT proper is going to have a single line.